# Why should I use DevExpress Advanced Custom Binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

So I've been searching around for an answer to this question, and I really haven't made any progress so I'm hoping someone here can help me.

I'm refering to this: http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/AdvancedCustomBinding

Now does this give me the ability to page on server side so large data sets don't bog down the initial request or is this more for if you want to do pure custom paging/filtering and what not, they never really give good examples of why you would want to go this route vs using there basic data binding. I'm still semi new to devExpress really only used there reporting engine so any advice will be much appreciated.

I'm really not sure how this is all completed on the devExpress side(server or client) and I really can't find any information on this.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late, but in case of intrest I will share my experiences here.

For example now I had a task to do a "compare" feature in one of our MVC gridviews. It means that don't caring any filtering or sorting, a custom "ghost" row should be following each "normal" row all the time, which holds data from - for example - last year. I mean don't caring filtering or sorting like all the filtering, sorting, grouping should work based only on the "standard" rows, and the "ghost" rows are jsut dumbly following their corresponding standard row after it.

Without custom binding, it is impossible to implement it, because in every standard data binding mechanism, the grid applies sorting, filtering, grouping to all of its visible rows, and I have no way to tell it that "these are just ghost rows".

I was confused until Custom Binding feature, but now I can simply query the standard data in the GetData handler, make a list from it, and insert my ghost rows all after sorting, filtering or grouping. Using a special model property for it, I can even make a different back color, or font to these special rows. I haven't tested it completely until now, but at first glance it looks good, and I have big hopes.

As a summary, with Custom Binding, as I interpret, basically you can process the UI request (sort, filter, etc.) in ANY way, you can put ANY data in the gridview as a result, just as if it were a pure HTML table, but you still have the great user interface for sorting, filtering, grouping, paging, etc.

EDIT: Currently filter builder and other advanced filtering options are not supported. Because I need them, now I cannot use custom binding. Looking forward to the complete support.